# React callback throwing undefined variable

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am a newbie to typescript and have a issue with one of my methods

```
const handleFileDescription = React.useCallback(
        (idToEdit: number, desc: string) => {
          var res = linq.from(fileList).firstOrDefault((t) => t.id === idToEdit);
          if (res !== undefined) {
            setFileList((prevState) => {
              return [
                ...prevState.filter((t) => t.id !== idToEdit),
                {
                  ...res,
                  desc: desc,
                  id: idToEdit,
                  file: res.file,
                },
              ];
            });
          }
        },
        [fileList, attachmentCount]
      );
```

This is where I am getting the error  file: res.file which says

```
'res' is possibly 'undefined'
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: What line is the error appearing on?

Comment: this is where is fails file: res.file,

Comment: I don't have a solution to your typescript error, but it seems like you can get rid of the `file: res.file` line because you've already spread `...res` earlier in that object.